# Was John's new dog at the end of the movie intentionally symbolic?

Tags: character, john-wick

After his wife's death, John receives a small puppy named Daisy in order to cope and provide the company to not grieve alone. 
At the end of the movie, after finishing his final act of retribution, John takes with him a stronger built pitbull puppy, and heads home.

Was this an intentional act of symbolism; with his first dog a representation of his fragile state after Helen's death, and the last dog a representation of a stronger, more willful John Wick?

Comment: I dunno, it can be interpreted as you wish..The movie has just left open the idea to get decoded to viewer him/her self. this could get closed as opinion based.

Comment: How is it opinion based if I'm asking if it really is intentional?

Comment: As I've said earlier, we have no official way to get to know that (far as I've come up with). So everything we can provide on this will be either heresay or speculated. Those answers may considered as opinion based. That's why I said it

Comment: @Vishwa This question is not opinion based at all.  We have questions like this all of the time and they can be answered by sources from filmmakers.  This is not an example of an opinion based question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no canon answer I've ever heard or read.

Also, don't forget that Wick was a hard-core hitman and killer from a very early age, so saying he was a "puppy" or "fragile" in the beginning doesn't hold a lot of merit, although it could be said his wife dying brought out the coldness that was always inside.

Comment: I think your missing it; Wick was fragile due to the loss of his wife and the killing of his dog (the only thing he has left to remind him of her) and stealing his car is what brings him back to his old life.

Comment: Basically he just lost everything that linked him to the life with his wife, which he had a huge attachment in deep inside. I think that's what made Wick go on thet revenge journey...

Answer (score 4):

If you pay close attention to the first movie, the pitbull that John chose was the only dog in the shelter that had the red stamp on his clipboard to be put down. He was saving that puppy from death. The symbolism is simple after that.